# Writing html in R - character encoding issues

Tags: html, r

I want to output html from R, and am hitting issues with particular characters.  To illustrate, a function:

```
output = function(str, fn){ sink(fn); cat(str); sink(); browseURL(fn) }
output("It's an apostrophe", 'good.html')
```

[image]

```
output("It’s a right single quote", 'bad.html')
```

[image]

Grateful for any tips towards a general solution that doesn't require ad-hoc character replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify an encoding in your HTML file, so the browser guesses — badly<sup>1</sup>. This is a general problem with text data, but for HTML there’s a simple solution: specify the encoding in the HTML; for instance:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        It’s a right single quote
    </body>
</html>
```

… and write this text to a file as UTF-8:

```
output = function (str, filename) {
    file = file(filename, encoding = 'UTF-8')
    on.exit(close(file))
    cat(str, file = file)
    browseURL(filename)
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Though it depends on a lot of factors: on my computer, your code happens to work.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. Simples